# Custom cdr fields for outgoing calls using asterisk

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I am trying to utilize the cdr logging (to mysql) using custom fields. The problem I am facing is only when an outbound call is placed, during inbound calls the custom field I am able to log no problem.

The reason I am having an issue is because the custom cdr field I need is a unique value for each user on the system.

sip.conf

```
 ...
 ...

 [sales_department](!)
 type=friend
 host=dynamic
 context=SalesAgents
 disallow=all
 allow=ulaw
 allow=alaw
 qualify=yes
 qualifyfreq=30


 ;; company sales agents:
 [11](sales_agent)
 secret=xxxxxx
 callerid="<...>"

 [12](sales_agent)
 secret=xxxxxx
 callerid="<...>"

 [13](sales_agent)
 secret=xxxxxx
 callerid="<...>"

 [14](sales_agent)
 secret=xxxxxx
 callerid="<...>"
```

extensions.conf

```
 [SalesAgents]
 include => Services

 ; Outbound calls
 exten=>_1NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@myprovider)


 ; Inbound calls
 exten=>100,1,NoOp()
    same => n,Set(CDR(agent_id)=11)
    same => n,CELGenUserEvent(Custom Event)
    same => n,Dial(${11_1},25)
    same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?busy:unavail)
    same => n(unavail),VoiceMail(11@asterisk)
    same => n,Hangup()
    same => n(busy),VoiceMail(11@asterisk)
    same => n,Hangup()

 exten=>101,1,NoOp()
    same => n,Set(CDR(agent_id)=12)
    same => n,CELGenUserEvent(Custom Event)
    same => n,Dial(${12_1},25)
    same => n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?busy:unavail)
    same => n(unavail),VoiceMail(12@asterisk)
    same => n,Hangup()
    same => n(busy),VoiceMail(12@asterisk)
    same => n,Hangup()

    ...
    ...
```

For the inbound section of the dialplan in the above example I am able to insert the custom cdr field (agent_id). But above it you can see for the Oubound section of the dialplan I have been stumped on how I would be able to tell the dialplan which agent_id is making the outbound call.

My Question: how to take the agent_id=[11] & agent_id=[12] and agent_id=[13] and agent_id=[14] etc and use that as a custom field for cdr on outbound calls?

Comment: Server configuration questions are off-topic on [so]. You should ask on [sf]

Comment: So why are there tags designated specifically to asterisk Mike?

Comment: Tags are for those people developing software that interfaces with or otherwise operates with Asterisk. Unless your question involves software development it's a server issue and belongs on [sf]

Comment: And this question is not regarding managing the server my asterisk system is hosted on it is specifically about programming the dialplan... Nothing to do with the server? I am afraid it fits better on stackoverflow than serverfault...

Comment: I disagree, but to get a clear idea of where this should go I've posted [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256706/when-does-server-configuration-become-programming) on [meta]

Comment: I'd say this is more appropriate than most Asterisk questions on StackOverflow. If this gets closed as "off-topic", you may as well close out 90% of the other Asterisk related questions.

Comment: @MikeW this is nothing to do with "Server Fault". This question must be under the tag 'Asterisk'.

Comment: @fortune Read the comments. You'll see that I raised that question on Meta. If you wish to contribute to the discussion you should do so there.

Comment: @MikeW, tnx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with the [CALLERID function](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+callerid). Try coding this in your dialplan as a test:

```
exten=6599,1,Answer()
exten=6599,n,Verbose(Caller id name=${CALLERID(name)})
exten=6599,n,Verbose(Caller id num=${CALLERID(num)})
exten=6599,n,Verbose(Caller id all=${CALLERID(all)})
exten=6599,n,SayNumber(${CALLERID(num)})
exten=6599,n,Hangup()
```

When you call 6599, you should see the number you're calling from displayed on the console, and hear your number played to you. In which case you should be able to do something like this for your logging:

```
same => n,Set(CDR(agent_id)=${CALLERID(num)})
```

---

**EDIT**

To use this approach, don't use the sip.conf `callerid=` to set or hide callerid. Instead, code that here in the dialplan, after you've read the callerid for your own use. For example:

```
same => n, Set(CALLERID(all)=""<>)
```